# Adjust values non linear

Tags: c#, math, pixel, sfml, brightness

I have a list of value pairs describing the distance to a given pixel and the brightness in percent I want to set:

```
Distance    Brightness
0px         100%
1px         99%
2px         98%
3px         97%
etc.
```

I want to transform my values so that the Brightness values form some kind of curve. The closer Values (up to 10px) are between 100-95 maybe and the rest will decrase more fast.

[image]

First row is the linear one I already have, the second one my goal.

Another example, what I want to achieve:
What I have now:

[image]

What I want to have:

[image]

I am programming a brighten-brush. As you can see the brightness is linear. I want it to become brighter in the middle of the circle and a greater "fall off" to the circle edges.

Code example to calculate the distance of the pixel and the brightness value

```
    private static Color LightenPixel(Vector2f center, Vector2f pixel, Color color)
    {
        //Calculate distance to circle origin
        double x = Math.Pow((double)(center.X - pixel.X),2);
        double y = Math.Pow((double)(center.Y - pixel.Y), 2);
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(x + y);

        //Get the percentual distance to the origin and flip the percentual value
        // E.G. 80% becomes 20% for brightness => closer to origin => brighter
        // -1 = 100% Darkness
        // +1 = 100% Brightness
        float brightness = (float)(1 - (distance * 100 / radius) / 100);
        return ChangeColorBrightness(color, brightness);
    }
```

EDIT:
Another example on how I want it:

[image]

Red is what I have, green is how I want it (somehow).

Comment: Can you show us what you already did? (do you have some code?)

Comment: I added a code example on how I calculate the distance of a given pixel to the origin of my circle and the brigthness value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use a [Log function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).
The log function decreases faster than the input.

```
Math.Log10(10D); // 1
Math.Log10(9D);  // 0.95
Math.Log10(8D);  // 0.90
Math.Log10(7D);  // 0.84
Math.Log10(6D);  // 0.77
Math.Log10(5D);  // 0.69
Math.Log10(4D);  // 0.60
Math.Log10(3D);  // 0.47
...
```

So basically, when you are closer to the center, you will have a value that is more and more small.
If what you need is the opposite (closer to the center=bigger value), then just use `1/Math.Log(distance)`;

So in your example, something like:

`brightness = (float)Math.Log10(brightness + 1);`

should make the trick...

Comment: Wow, seems so simple. I was looking for possible ways to implement this and a logistic function seemed to be perfect. Can you tell me how to vary the "fall off" with the Log function?

Comment: I can probably help If you can provide a zip where I can play with the source code... otherwise it's a bit tricky :)

Comment: Cool :) Here you can download the VS 2013 solution + project http://www.nakkvarr.net/sfmlBrush.7z  ... I am using the SFML NuGet package for the graphics

Comment: The methods "LightenPixel" and "ChangeColorBrightness" should be the interesting methods

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but that is not exactly what I need :( I played around with it but couldn't find an optimal value. Now I created a little test application visualizing the "curve" ... if you want to check it out: http://nakkvarr.net/Falloff.7z ... I also added another screenshot on how I want the curve to look like (or similar)

Comment: For me your green function looks like a sigmoïde function (see https://www.google.ch/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=prKrVaGEHKKo8weKoYGAAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=1%2F(1%2B(e%5E(-x))) ). Sorry, I'm afraid I cannot help you more than that...

Comment: No problem. I tried a logistic function and it's working well. But I figured out, that this was not the main problem. I calculated the colors wrong. It looks way better in HSL (adjusting L) and a linear fall off :) Thanks for your time!